# Does Nginx support ssh connections?

Tags: php, nginx, sql

I want to build a site with nginx as HTTP server and MariaDB as SQL server.

I'm searching in Google if nginx support (or its included) the ssh support to execute ssh_connect thru PHP files, but I can't find absolutely nothing

Does anyone know if ssh functions is avaible with nginx? A reference link will be apreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP needs to support it, not nginx.  Nginx just needs to support PHP, not every PHP function.

If it did, why would you need to install PHP in the first place?

Comment: Oh, okay, I tought it depends too to the server is running PHP, thank you.